# HTML page break for word - page-break-before:always not working

Tags: php, html, css, ms-word

I made a HTML for a word document and created it via `file_put_contents('document.doc', $html_source);`

The problem is that the style used as following:

```
style='page-break-before:always'
```

Doesn't do anything.

Any ideas or solutions?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do: http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/720863-page-break-html-word-email

Comment: So you lie to MS Word about file extension and expect it to do whatever you want?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do here. Perhaps post a bit of the HTML source and what you're trying to apply that style to.

Comment: Well, make a document in Word with multiple pages, save it has HTML, then open it with Word again. Do it respect page breaks? if yes, then read the HTML code and see what propietary crap Word expect, and use that. If don't respect line breaks, you are out of luck.

Comment: As I see it, there is no way this would work using a simple file_put_contents. The best option is to use a GNU Word document creator with PHP like this one http://phpword.codeplex.com/.

Thanks for all your comments though!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word will only recognize this style as long as it's applied to a `<br />` element.

```css
.pagebreak {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
```

```html
<br class="pagebreak" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<div class=”WordSection1”></div>
```

I am was creating a word document from an HTML table.